# How to stop DOM javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling

I have the following code with intention of stoping the handling of mouse clicks on webpage, after the very first mouse click.

```
    // The following is inside the onload function of html BODY.
    var     theLeftSide     = document.getElementById("leftSide");
    var     theBody         = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    theBody.addEventListener("click",  function() {
        gameOver( theLeftSide, theBody );
    });

    ....................
    function gameOver(theLeftSide, theBody){  
        alert("That is not the correct face. Game over.");
        theBody.onclick = null;
        theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
    }
```

But, the mouse handling does not stop (as indicated by the alerts). I did some search, to confirm that javascript passes "object parameters" by reference. When i step through the debugger, i see the event handler (theBody.onclick) is getting set to NULL.  Why is this change in gameOver() not affecting the webpage body ?

---

UPDATE:
Thanks to all the comments. Even though i realized my mistake when i took a break after my original post, all replies were helpful to me to learn things that i did not know before, especially since they induced me to read docs further.  I had to modify the accepted answer, because the variables were
local to a function and not global. So, current code which has solved my trouble looks like this ::

```
    theBody.addEventListener("click",  function clickListener() {
        gameOver( theLeftSide, theBody, clickListener );
    });

    And outside the function where the above statement is, i have

    function gameOver(theLeftSide_param, theBody_param, clickListener_param) {
        alert("That is not the correct face. Game over.");
        theBody_param.removeEventListener("click", clickListener_param);
        theLeftSide_param.lastChild.onclick = null;
    }
```

clickListener had to be passed as a parameter, because that was not a global and was not visible outside to gameOver().

Comment: Use `removeEventListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers assigned using `addEventListener` are not in the `onclick` property (since that can only hold one function, and you can add an arbitrary number of listeners). Use `removeEventListener` to remove a handler added with `addEventListener`.

Since you need to provide the listener function to this, and it has to match the function that was added, you should move that function out to a named function, since two anonymous functions will never be equal.

```
function clickListener() {
    gameOver(theLeftSide, theBody);
}
theBody.addEventListener("click", clickListener);

function gameOver(theLeftSide, theBody) {
    alert("That is not the correct face. Game over.");
    theBody.removeEventListener("click", clickListener);
    theLeftSide.lastChild.onclick = null;
}
```

Comment: Accepted the first comment as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `onclick` property does not affect event handlers added with `.addEventListener()` in any way.  If you want to remove those event handlers, then you can use `.removeEventListener()` on them.

Note: a common technique for temporarily blocking all click events is to insert a transparent div above all your content and it will grab all the click events and then use a click handler on that transparent div that stops propragation.  This is a technique that can be used when there are many different even handlers, perhaps some of which you don't even control directly or when you want to block them only temporarily and then restore them later.

Comment: Patrik has given code in his answer, for this technique.  So, I guess all mouse events will be delivered only to this <div> since it covers the entire visible webpage.  There would be no need to use stopPropagation() or event handlers in this case - is this correct ?

Comment: If you don't use `.stopPropagation()`, then events will propagate up to the body, document and window objects.  If there are event handlers there, they will get click events on the div, so `.stopPropagation()` would be recommended.  If there are no click event handlers on those higher level objects, then it would not matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop mouse clicks after the first click then you can place a div overlay after the first mouseclick, tough not 100% sure if this is the answer you is looking for.

[**DEMO:**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgrdsgjL/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dis_click"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="alert ('You clicked me')">Click me first!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="alert ('you didnt follow the instructions!')">then after click me!</button>
```

**CSS:**

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
document.onmouseup = myMouseUpHandler;

function myMouseUpHandler(){  
    document.getElementById("dis_click").className = "overlay";
}
```